# Import linux environment variable from shell file

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I want to import environment variables set in my linux user shell file into my perl script ?
And i don't want to parse for key=value pairs.
How can this be done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590937/how-do-i-import-environment-settings-into-my-perl-program

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349189/importing-environment-variables-to-perl

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Env`module.

`$ENV{Variablename}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get them from your current shell rather than an arbitrary file, you actually *have* access to all your environment variables, such as with:

```
pax> perl -e 'print $ENV{"HOME"}."\n"'
/home/pax
```

or, if you want to enumerate them all (in sorted order, for example):

```
foreach $key (sort keys %ENV) {
    print "[$key] -> [$ENV{$key}]\n";
}
```

Comment: `perl -e 'print $ENV{"HOME"} . "\n"'` is more common on command line.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the solution here: http://darkdiary.ru/users/TLoD_Snake/3233201/comment/

Perl executes your shell command file and reexecutes itself if it figures out that shell command was not executed before.

I've found this solution from TLoD_Snake here on StackOverflow, but I can not find the exact question, so I just point you to his blog.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done with the [`Env::Modify`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify) module.

```
use Env::Modify 'source';
source("$ENV{HOME}/.my_user_shell_file");
```